# List users from Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, active-directory

I've set up Spring Security so that it will authenticate against a Active Directory. How can I get a list of all the users in my @Controller?

Background: I have a controller where I want the admin to be able to assign different users into groups. I want to provide a list of users she can select from, and this should be a filtered list of users in the AD.

Cheers

Nik

Comment: And why should that be a responsiblity of Spring Security? Just create a repository that uses a `LdapTemplate` to retrieve the users from the AD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to retrieve it from AD, spring security not provide, or store list of users, it is using AD for that and use AuthenticationManager to integrate with AD or DB contains the users profiles.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Security you can get List of all users those are currently logged-in into the system.
by using this code in your controller.

```
@Autowired
private SessionRegistryImpl sessionRegistry;
```

List principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();

Comment: interesting, but probably not the answer to the question.